# Trouble having SDL_TTF and OPENGL work together

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-ttf

For a game I'm working on, I'm hoping to use OpenGL for a lot of the graphics and `SDL_TTF` for the text. I can get both to work but not at the same time. Here's my code (based off Lazy Foo):

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"

const bool useOpenGl = true;

//The surfaces
SDL_Surface *message = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

//The event structure
SDL_Event event;

//The font that's going to be used
TTF_Font *font = NULL;

//The color of the font
SDL_Color textColor = {255, 255, 255};

void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL)
{
    //Holds offsets
    SDL_Rect offset;

    //Get offsets
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    //Blit
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}

bool init()
{
    SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    if (useOpenGl)
    {
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode (1280, 720, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_OPENGL); //With SDL_OPENGL flag only opengl is sceen, without only text is
    } else {
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode (1280, 720, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    }

    TTF_Init();

    SDL_WM_SetCaption ("TTF Not Working With OpenGL", NULL);

    if (useOpenGl)
    {
        glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0, screen->w, screen->h, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    return true;
}

bool load_files()
{
    font = TTF_OpenFont ("arial.ttf", 28);

    return true;
}

void clean_up()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface (message);

    TTF_CloseFont (font);
    TTF_Quit();

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //Quit flag
    bool quit = false;

    init();
    load_files();

    if (useOpenGl)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //clearing the screen
        glPushMatrix();


        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(1280, 0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(1280, 720);
        glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.1);
        glVertex2f(0, 720);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
        glFlush();
    }

    //Render the text
    message = TTF_RenderText_Solid (font, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", textColor);

    //Apply the images to the screen
    apply_surface (0, 150, message, screen);

    //I'm guessing this is where the problem is coming from
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    SDL_Flip (screen);


    while (quit == false)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent (&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    clean_up();

    return 0;
}
```

If the variable `useOpenGl` is set to false the program will only use `SDL_TTF`, if it's set to true it will use both `SDL_TTF` and OpenGL.
From playing around with it the problem seems to be with whether or not I use the "SDL_OPENGL" flag when creating the window.

Answer (score 0):

SDL_TTF uses software rendering and is not compatible with OpenGL mode.

You might have to look for another library such as [FTGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/develop) or [freetype-gl](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/).